# How to convert HH:mm:ss into int?

Tags: android, datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
int s = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(new Date()).replace(":"," "));
```

I am converting the time which is give in string to int using **integer.parseInt** but gives number not calid exception

Comment: and where is your input String in format of  "HH:mm:ss" ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
int s = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Tested  with:

```
Log.d("Parsed date", "date: "+s);
```

Result: 
D/Parsed date: date: 111405

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String time = "10:10:00";
String[] timeArray = time.split(":");
int HH = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
int mm = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
int ss = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"" empty space` instead because numbers do not have space in it.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
int s = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(new Date()).replace(":",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace the `:` by a space which leaves you with a string like `11 03 17`. This is not a valid integer.

A simpler approach would be to leave out the `:` characters already in the format: `new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");`